# Datagrid view in C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website which contains data from oracle database , I got connection and data populate through grid view , the data is PO number , and orderdate I want to check if orderdate

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var orderdate = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (orderdate < now)
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your questions isn't clear, please explain further. Also why don't you set the color for the entire row instead of each cell?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand that too. Try rephrase it.